# Why is COUNT returning the wrong number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm very new to programming and trying to figure what I'm doing wrong. I have a database with two tables. One is called "addresses and the other is called "tablePlayers". I'm trying to count the number of times a specific person's name appears in the "winner" column and then update it under the "W" column in the table "tablePlayers" on the row of that same person's name.

Here's the code I'm using

```
c.execute("UPDATE tablePlayers SET W = COUNT(winner) FROM addresses WHERE winner ='Mika'")
```

Here's what the tables look like in DB Browser for SQLite. As you can see "Mika" only appears once under the "winners" column. But the count says 6 in the other table, and is only printed on one row and not the one with the matching name

[addresses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vwHB.png)

[tablePlayers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3D86.png)

Comment: You are trying to count the values in a table you never name in the query, that is not going to work. You will have to do a subquery to get the count. See the example at 2.2 of https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you why exactly it is going wrong, but I would recommend that you use parentheses and a SELECT statement to build a nested query. For example, your query could rather look like this:

`UPDATE tablePlayers SET W = (SELECT COUNT(winner) FROM addresses WHERE winner ='Mika') WHERE Name='Mika'`

You could also do the more general case and do it for all names at once:

`UPDATE tablePlayers SET W = (SELECT COUNT(winner) FROM addresses WHERE winner=tablePlayers.Name)`